# Adjust laptop display out of range

Tags: display, brightness

I have Dell Precision m4800. I set display backlight to 0% however it is still very bright. Is it possible to make it darker more? I think it should be (device has that option) because when adaptive brightness service is active - backlight seems to be darker on dark images.

Comment: Check BIOS level settings for display brightness and see if those many any difference.

Comment: Does it react when using the functions keys to adjust the brightness levels? If not, you might be missing a driver